Convergent trigonometric series
I was checking the convergence of the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(n+ \frac{1}{n})\pi$$
My first step is to simplify the seres since $\sin n\pi = 0$ for all $n$.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(n+ \frac{1}{n})\pi = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin\frac{\pi}{n}$$
Using the comparison test:
$$\frac{\pi}{2n}<\sin\frac{\pi}{n}<\frac{\pi}{n}$$
Based on that, I've concluded that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(n+ \frac{1}{n})\pi$ is a divergent series. However, when I was looking for the correct answer, it said it's convergent. Any ideas why?

Your simplification is wrong. $f(a+b) \neq f(a)+f(b)$, unless f is linear. The trigonometric functions are non-linear.

Here is well known formula you could use: $sin(A+B) = sin(A)cos(B) +sin(B)cos(A)$.

@M. Wind
Or simply its special case: $\sin(A+\pi)=-\sin A.$
